# I can't use a function of bstHeight C++

Tags: c++

I got a problem with height of a binary tree... I got a function (hope it's good) but I cant use it in any possible way :(

Can someone tell me how to do that?

```
int treeHeight(BSTNode *up)
{
   if (up == NULL)
   {
      return 0;
   }

   int left = treeHeight(up->left);
   int right = treeHeight(up->right); 

   return 1 + std::max(left, right);
}
```

ok and class code:

```
class BSTNode{
public:
  BSTNode * up, * left, * right;
  int key;
  private:
    void insertBST(BSTNode * & root, int k);
    int treeHeight(BSTNode *p);
};
```

ok and main :

```
 BSTNode * root = NULL;
  int i, k, n=0;
cout<<"Number of elements : ";
cin>>n;
cout<<endl;

  srand(time(NULL));        

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)   
  {
    k = 1 + rand() % 10+1;    
    cout << k << " ";      
    insertBST(root,k);      
  }
cout<<endl;
```

How to add that height function in main?

Comment: I don't understand. Are you asking how to call a function? You clearly know how to call a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
int treeHeight(BSTNode *up)
{
    ...
}

int main(...)
{
    ...
    int iHeight = treeHeight(root);
}
```